# JQuery ,each() with UI.sortable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have an unordered list that's sortable using jQuery ui. I need the data-priority attribute to be 1-6 (or highest number) on every sort or re-sort. As it stands it sets it on load and doesn't re-set it after the sort.

I made a fiddle for you. It's probably something easy but I can't figure it out. >(

```
$("#priority-list").sortable(); 
    $("#priority-list li").each( function(i){
    $(this).attr("data-priority", "pri-" + (i + 1));
});
```

Thanks!

[link for jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kyle_sevenoaks/vrgSa/)

Comment: You ar not calling the 2 last lines. You must create a function and call it each time a line is moved to re-compute attributes. Give a look at the doc, the "change" event : http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you aren't executing the code to do the prioritization after you sort.

http://jsfiddle.net/3CWBt/

```
$(function(){

    $("#priority-list").sortable({
        stop: setPriority
    });
    setPriority();

    function setPriority() {
        $("#priority-list li").each( function(i){
            $(this).attr("data-priority", "pri-" + (i + 1));
        });
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#priority-list").sortable({
    stop : function( event, ui ) {
         $("#priority-list li").each( function(i){
             $(this).attr("data-priority", "pri-" + (i + 1));
         });
     }
});
```